# Does expat include quotes that delimit attribute values?

Tags: c++, xml, expat-parser

I'm learning to use Expat to parse XML. Suppose I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<data id="the-id" type="my_type" size="93">
```

When the handler that I specified for `XML_SetElementHandler` is called with an attribute list, do the attributes include the quote characters used to delimit them?

Answer (score 1):

No, see examples/outline.c

```
  for (i = 0; attr[i]; i += 2) {
    printf(" %" XML_FMT_STR "='%" XML_FMT_STR "'", attr[i], attr[i + 1]);
  }
```

```
data id='the-id' type='my_type' size='93'
```